# Configure Xbmc/kodi via command line

Tags: kodi

I have installed xbmc/kodi on a headless raspbian (no keyboard, no mouse).
I thought to configure it with the webserver configuration tools, but I am not able to enable it as I cannot access the GUI: how can enable it via command line?

Comment: http://kodi.wiki/view/web_interface. This helped instantaneously

Answer (score 17):

**TLDR;** I'm working on the same setup; this answer turned into a log of my investigations: see below for a config which works for me.

---

**Background:** I've followed the tutorial: [Setting up a Raspberry Pi with file sharing and screen sharing for Macs](http://dennistt.net/2013/09/15/raspberry-pi/). I've also installed [Shairport Sync](https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync).

I installed kodi as recommended in the [documentation](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_on_Raspberry_Pi#Raspbian):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

Then I can start kodi from the CLI `kodi`, or from the desktop interface (mirrored on the Mac) under `Menu > Sound & Video > Kodi`. I have the Pi plugged in to my TV via HDMI, and Kodi shows on the TV, whilst the desktop shows on the Mac.. I haven't found any way of switching apps to Kodi via VNC, or switching spaces (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd> shows that that I've only got one space active).

### Configuring Kodi via SSH

- SSH into your server
- `nano /home/pi/.kodi/userdata/guisettings.xml` ([Forum: Managing Network Settings by SSH](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=79539))
- search for the `<services>` section and edit the following properties, which vary from the default:

.

```
<services>
    ...
    <airplay>true</airplay>
    ...
    <esallinterfaces>true</esallinterfaces>
    ...
    <upnprenderer>true</upnprenderer>
    <upnpserver>true</upnpserver>
    ...
    <webserver>true</webserver>
    ...
</services>
```

- `killall -9 kodi.bin`
- start Kodi: `kodi`
- see what ports Kodi is listening on `netstat -lnptu | grep kodi`

.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3805/kodi.bin
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9777            0.0.0.0:*                           3805/kodi.bin
```

#### Potentially helpful tips:

The [services documentation](http://kodi.wiki/view/Settings/Services) lists the default http username:`kodi`, password:`kodi`

The logs for kodi can be viewed at:

```
less ~/.kodi/temp/kodi.log
```

[Fing](http://www.overlooksoft.com/fing) is a free app on ios and android which will detect devices on the local network, display their MAC addresses, and scan ports.  From my iPad, I can see `#22:SSH`, `#548:AFP`, `#5000:upnp`, `#5900:VNC`, but no `:9090` <kbd>:'(</kbd>. If I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on the pi, Fing can see `#8000:http-alt`.

See if you can hit the configured port from your browser: http://<username>:<password>@<xbmc_ip>:<xbmc_port> (See: [iPhone/iPod Touch - no xbmc instances were found](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=143295))

[Further options](http://kodi.wiki/view/Advancedsettings.xml) can be configured by editing (or creating) `/home/xbmc/.xbmc/userdata/advancedsettings.xml`.

Deleting either of the xml configs will cause them to be recreated with defaults.

---

Whilst [installing Shairport Sync](https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync#building-and-installing) (prior to Kodi), I read:

> You should not have more than one zeroconf service on the same system

I've definitely got [Avahi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) running, and [kodi uses avahi, too](http://kodi.wiki/view/Avahi_Zeroconf).. *Clutching at straws: is there a conflict?*

Firing `avahi-browse -a` returns a list of services all over my network, including:

```
+   eth0 IPv4 Kodi (pi)                                     _xbmc-jsonrpc._tcp   local
+   eth0 IPv4 Kodi (pi)                                     _xbmc-events._udp    local
```

---

**Update:** I attached a keyboard and went and toggled all the switches which seemed relevant to connectivity. I now connect via http (http://[localIP]:8080).  I diffed my updates with the default config, and pasted the relevant lines above.